# How to search Mongodb models by date?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using Node.js mongodb. I have a model like this

```
const calendarSchema = new Schema ({
    title: String,
    start: String, //start date
    end: String, // end date
    endDate: String,
    sessionsRan: Number,
    _user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    
})
```

What is the best way to query mongodb for this? I need to find documents where date < today and isActive: true.

I am currently doing this but not sure how implement a date search

```
const calendar = await Calendar.find({isActive: "active"})
```

Comment: Your design is wrong. **Never** store date values as string, use proper `Date` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [$lt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) mongodb operator, you can query against the **date** field alongside `isActive` field.

```
{start:{$lt: new Date().toISOString()}, isActive: true}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://onecompiler.com/mongodb/3yhqu5ppr)

Note:

- Ensure your dates are saved as **ISOString**
- Your schema for dates should be constructed with `new Date()` object rather than a String.